# Android Studio 2.3.1 design overwrites text xml

Tags: android, xml

I am switching between text and design view in android studio and it seems that whenever I make a change in the text (xml) and the change back to design my changes are overwritten by something random. I want the text changes to take priority over the design tab.

For example:

I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.foo.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

change it into this in text view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.foo.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

when I switch to Design it somehow resets back to the first one. I want to see my changes even if they are wrong, without starting an emulator. I tried googling it but I can't see anybody else reporting this.

Comment: It is possible that your problem is that you are using `ConstraintLayout` but have not yet applied any constraints. Start adding the constraints, then set the width, and see if the width sticks.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I will do that. I didn't add the ConstraintLayout, as it was added when the project was generated. I chose a min SDK, gingerbread...